# .Net Web API - Managers vs. Service vs Repository - where should my logic reside in?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some logic that performs operations on objects that are passed in. E.g.:

```
  GetTotals(Item items){...}  //Run through item props, sum them up

  CombineItems(Item item1, Item item2){...}  //Merge 1 into 2
```

Where should the simpler logic like this belong to, semantically? I won't be retrieving anything from the DB. Is it more likely to be a:

- Service?
- Manager?
- Helper?
- Something else?

PS. If Helper class or others, would it be common for it to be dependency-injected into the parent class calling it?

Answer (score 0):

If those methods are static or they provide static logic to `Item` and it's shared by different callers, you could try make an extension method, so you could call them like

```
item1.CombineItems(item2, item3...);
```

Myself prefer extension method over static Helper because extension methods can be discovered by Intellisense.

There are also reasons you could make them into a service:

- they are business logic
- they need a lifetime, or need to be managed by DI container
- they need to be mocked in unit tests

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the project size / type and architecture. There could be multiple ways to organize it.

1. As a helper classes usually as a part of independent class library called SolutionName.Utils in a case classical N-tier monolith mostly for web apps.
2. As a part of Command / Query class logic in a case of DDD / CQRS based approaches.
3. As a simple method of class to which its related (usually it's for small apps)
4. Like extension method, on large projects it could be difficult to maintain.

As for DI, in classical monolith usually such things are not injected as they are independent from other parts of the logic and could be easily covered with unit tests.
If such logic blocks / or creates dependencies with other parts of the logic and therefore could not be fully covered with unit tests, than it means it needs to be injected.